# How php, javascript and mysql to one combo, if clicked comes in another through another query

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have tried to get problem to be done through many different post this forum have. But couldn't reach into my specific goal.
I am trying to have data from a column in a table to a combo, then if any one data clicked, it should list to another combo from another column in another table according to data clicked. 
Please check my site: raihans.co.uk, user: dbuser, passwd. Then hover User Log In/Out, click on 'DB Test'. 
As a sample, you may have a look the combo created on the top. At the bottom I have tried myself with mysql, javascript and php. Succeded to populate my first column in 1st Combo from one of my Table. But can't carry to second or third. 
Please have a look the code. I have used to populate the two combos. I am not sure, where I have done the mistake/s. Please help me on this. Thanking you in advance.

```
<html><div><head><?php
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","db_user_name","db_user_passwd");
    if (!$link) {    die('Could not connect to Database: ' . mysql_error());   }
    mysql_select_db("db_name",$link);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
    $category = array();
    $query = "SELECT State_Name FROM Test_State";
    $q_result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$q_result) {     die('Could not make query: ' . mysql_error());      }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q_result))  {    ?>
category[] = ["<?php  $row;    }    ?>"];

function fillSelect(sel,ary,nxt){
 if (ary&&sel.form){
 var frm=sel.form,nme=sel.name.replace(/\d/g,""),i=Number(sel.name.replace(/\D/g,""))+1,nxt=frm[nxt],opts=sel.options,oary=[],z0=nxt==sel?0:1,z1=0,z1a;
 while (frm[nme+i]){
   frm[nme+i].length=1;
   frm[nme+i].selectedIndex=0;
   i++;
 }
 for (;z0<opts.length;z0++){
   if (opts[z0].selected&&ary[opts[z0].value]){
     oary=oary.concat(ary[opts[z0].value]);
 }  }
 if (nxt){
   for (;z1<oary.length;z1++)  {    nxt.options[z1+1]=new Option(oary[z1],oary[z1]);   }
 nxt.selectedIndex=0;
 }   }   }
 function getValue(isValue) {   alert(isValue);   }

 function init() {   fillSelect(document.forms[0]['List1'],category,'List1')   }

 navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" ? attachEvent('onload', init, false) : addEventListener('load', init, false);
 </script></div></head>

 <body>
 <form action="">

 <select name='List1' onchange="fillSelect(this,category,'List2')">
     <option value="" selected>Select a country</option>
 <?php
    $category = "SELECT Country_Name FROM Test_Country";
    $query_result = mysql_query($category);
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result))
    {    ?>
 <option value = "<?php echo $result['Country_Name']?>"><?php echo $result['Country_Name']?></option>
 <?php    } ?>
 </select>

 <select name='List2' onchange="getValue(this.value)">
 <option selected>Select State</option>
 </select>
 </form></body></html>
```

Comment: In JavaScript, do not use browser sniffing, but feature detection.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best technique for you is to use the example code you have exactly as it is, with one change: when you build the page in PHP you want to dynamically create the categories array.  You can do this very neatly by creating the array in PHP, and then use [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to turn it into javascript.

Here I have tried to show you how to build the `$categories` variable that you can use with your existing Javascript.  I haven't tested it, so you should expect a few errors.  But the technique is what is important.

```
<html><div><head>
    <?php
        $link = mysql_connect("localhost","db_user_name","db_user_passwd");
        if (!$link)
            die('Could not connect to Database: ' . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("db_name",$link);

        $categories = array();

        $countryQuery = "select State_Name FROM Test_State";
        $countryResult = mysql_query($countryQuery);
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($countryResult) )
            $categories['startList'][] = $row['State_Name'];

        /*  I don't know your db schema, so I'm making it up as I go along
            A db row of "California","SFO" becomes:
                $categories["California"] = array("SFO");
            Subsequent airports in California are appended to the same array.
        */
        $airportQuery = "select Airport_Name, State_Name from Test_Airport";
        $airportResult = mysql_query($airportQuery);
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($airportResult) )
            $categories[$row['State_Name']][] = $row['Airport_Name'];

        // you can use the same technique to build a map of airports->resorts
    ?>

    <!-- Now we just need to export the big PHP array as a Javascript variable.
        Use the json_encode() function. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $category = <?php echo json_encode($categories); ?> ;
    </script>
```

I have some additional notes for you, as well:

First, don't use the mysql library.  It has been deprecated for new code.  Use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Second, I think you are confused about how PHP and Javascript interact.  In a word, they don't.  PHP runs and creates the page, then the browser loads the page and runs the Javascript.  It looks like you are expecting the Javascript to interact with the PHP, and that isn't going to happen unless you employ AJAX techniques.  You are not yet ready for AJAX.

Third, if you are going to ask other people to read your code, you should format it nicely first.  Messy code is very hard to read, and most people will just avoid it and not answer your question.  If you want other people to help you with your code, you need to be willing to put some extra effort into your questions.